# why my label is not self updating?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I had read a number of posts on update_idletasks().  I thought I understood, and I add that into code. the label supposed to have the # 3 show up because i only have 3 rows of record, and it didn't.

I did use a button, and the label works, but the update_idletask() no.

is there way to not use the button to make this label self updating by using update_idletasks()?

I am thinking it's not working because it didn't going into a loop?
please direct me.

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as t
import time

class SampleApp(t.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        t.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
#GUI-------------------------------------
        self.labelVariable=t.StringVar()
        self.label=t.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable, bg="yellow", width=50, height=20)
        self.label.pack(fill=t.X, expand=1)


        #self.button=t.Button(self, text="get status", pady=5, command=self.status)
        #self.button.pack(anchor=t.S, fill=t.X, expand=1)


#formula______________________________________

    def status(self):
        conn=sqlite3.connect("employees.db")
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Company")
        self.labelVariable.set(cursor.fetchone()[0])

        self.update_idletasks()
        self.after(0,self.status)


app = SampleApp(None)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `self.status()`....and `self.update_idletasks()` isn't necessary.  And if you're going to open a connection, you must close it as well.

Change your class to this:

```
class SampleApp(t.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        t.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize()


    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.labelVariable=t.StringVar()
        self.label=t.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable, bg="yellow", width=50, height=20)
        self.label.pack(fill=t.X, expand=1)
        self.status()

    def status(self):
        conn=sqlite3.connect("employees.db")
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Company")
        self.labelVariable.set(cursor.fetchone()[0])
        conn.close()
        self.after(10,self.status)
```

Note: you shouldn't use `.after` with 0 or practically anything under 10 for the `delay` argument (the unit is in ms).

Comment: I strongly recommend against `self.after(0, ...)`. You should use a bigger number. Using zero means that the "after" queue never empties, which can prevent normal events from being processed. Even a value of `1` (one) would be better than zero, though a much bigger number like `10` or `100` would be better.

Comment: You're 100% right, I just used the one from the OP's example

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, Bryan and abccd.  I appreciate it.  I updated the codes, but still not seeing the number on my label.  the "3" ,rows of record.